# Objective-C get subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have a UIViewController Subclass,
let's call it MyAppBaseViewController:
and

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSString *subclassName = ...;
    NSLog(@"%@ did appear", subclassName);
}
```

How would I be able to get the subclass name, not the name of the current class, from within the parent, without adding any properties to the implementation or anything like that?

Comment: `NSStringFromClass(self.class)`

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@ did appear", [self class]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused.

An object is an instance of some subclass. It can, and often does, inherit from a long chain of parent classes.

The object is still a particular class.

If you use

```
NSString *myClassName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%s", class_getName([self class)];
```

It will give you the name of the current object's class. Not the parent class. The current object.

### Edit:

As the other poster pointed out, the function NSStringFromClass is much easier. Use that instead:

```
NSString *myClassName = NSStringFromClass([self class]);
```

Comment: Why not use NSStringFromClass() here?

Comment: er... 'cause I couldn't remember the name of the method, and couldn't find it? That would be simpler than my code. Thanks for the correction. (voted). Now I'm off to edit my answer...